# Python dataframe insert into Azure SQL

Tags: python-3.x, azure-sql-database

I would like to insert multiple records from pandas dataframe into MS Azure table via python:

```
lst = [
  ('111', 'AA', 'AAA'),
  ('222', 'BB', 'BBB'),
  ('333', 'CC', 'CCC')
]

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.fast_executemany = True
SQLCommand = ("INSERT INTO [dbo].[ServiceRequestCollection_tmp] (ObjectID,BuyerMainContactPartyID,BuyerMainContactPartyName) VALUES (?,?,?);")
cursor.execute(SQLCommand, lst)
cursor.commit()
```

Unfortunately, system generates the following error. Can I kindly ask you to help me

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ("A TVP's rows must all be the same size.", 'HY000')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

SystemError: <built-in function utf_16_le_encode> returned a result with an error set

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

SystemError: encoding with 'utf-16le' codec failed (SystemError: <built-in function utf_16_le_encode> returned a result with an error set)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/103925alf1/PycharmProjects/p10/p11.py", line 35, in <module>
    cursor.execute(SQLCommand, lst)
SystemError: <class 'pyodbc.Error'> returned a result with an error set

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly set `cursor.fast_executemany = False`.

Also, you can upgrade to `pyodbc 4.0.24` (or newer) and use `setinputsizes` to specify the parameter type, etc..

```
sql = "INSERT INTO #issue295 (txt, dec) VALUES (?, ?)"
params = [('Ώπα', 3.141)]
# explicitly set parameter type/size/precision
crsr.setinputsizes([(pyodbc.SQL_WVARCHAR, 50, 0), (pyodbc.SQL_DECIMAL, 18, 4)])
crsr.fast_executemany = True
crsr.executemany(sql, params)
```

For more details, you could refer to this [wiki](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Tips-and-Tricks-by-Database-Platform#using-fast_executemany-with-a-temporary-table).